# PHP - PDO - Oracle - LONG - data too large to buffer, truncating to fit

Tags: php, oracle, pdo

I'm using PDO with Oracle, and when I'm trying to use "fetchAll" on a column of type "LONG", if the data inside is more than 512 characters, the following warning appears:

> Warning: PDOStatement::fetchAll() [pdostatement.fetchall]: column X data was too large for buffer and was truncated to fit it in (...) on line 69

PHP Version 5.2.17
Oracle Version: 11g
PDO drivers: oci

Comment: pdo_oci is still experimental, and there are several similar bugs logged that either are not resolved, or are in the process of being resolved. eg: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=54379&edit=1

Comment: And Oracle doesn't provide developers for the PDO driver. They only support their OCI8 extension.

Comment: Try changing the adapter to `oracle`.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. One of the selected columns was of oracle timestamp data type so in my case helped encapsulating this column with defined format of date, for example like below:

`SELECT TO_CHAR(column_name, 'YY/MM/DD HH24:MI:SS') as column_name
FROM table`

Answer (score 1):

I still had this issue in 2020 using PHP 7.2 and the latest version of the PHP PDO OCI library. The solution I had was to use oci_connect instead, and pull the long field using that instead.

I found a good reference was using: https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/fuecks-lobs.html

Comment: Yep, OCI8 still has better features and is recommended over PDO_OCI.  Even without quirks, a dedicated driver has some inherent advantages over a common access layer (e.g PDO)

Answer (score 0):

Detail:
i.e. for column which presents the problem.
in varchar2( X ), X = desired size.
example:
select cast( name_column AS varchar2(70) )as nickname from table;

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but in my case the data type was varchar. The problem was thas I was using varchar(3) to store things like 'NÃO'. Since the 'Ã' uses more than 1 byte to be stored, when I tried to fetchAll I had the same warning.

Check if you are storing a numeric value that is bigger than the size of a Long. Change the size of the column in Oracle.

Answer (score -1):

You must change the size of varchar in oracle, example:
if you need 50 chars of another symbols, you must write

```
varchar2(100)
```

and in model yii you must write `length 100`